# How to find height and width of column's child in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using a stack with alignment of center,

as a children i am using two container, here i want to give size of second container based on first container's size..

if first container is 100 by height...second container height must be 1/4 like 25.

I dont want to place second container inside first container,

I have shared an output which i dont want....in this output all second container height is fixed...i want it based on first container

[image]

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
        
              SizedBox(
                height: 80,
                width: 80,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: CustomWidget(color: Colors.red,),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 160,
                width: 160,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: CustomWidget(color: Colors.green,),
                ),

              ),
           
             
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and here is custom widget which is drawing a container inside a container

```
class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  const CustomWidget({Key? key,required this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          // container one
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: color,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          //container two
          height: 40,//this should be 1/4 height of container one
          width: 40,// this should be 1/4 of  width of container one
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            shape: BoxShape.circle
          ),
          child: Center(child: Text('2')),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: for your CustomWidget, Container inside another one seems better to me.

Answer (score 1):

I mean the 40 width and 40 height is hardcoded in your Container. Pass it from the parent widget to this widget and calculate it dynamically:

```
height: height * 1/4,
width: width * 1/4
```

Comment: Is there no other way?

Comment: Why you need another way? This is the simplest solution ... you could else try it with a  LayoutBuilder to get the parent constraint or with a GlobalKey and RenderObject.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FractionallySizedBox, I will prefer

```dart
class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  const CustomWidget({Key? key, required this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: 1 / 4,
        heightFactor: 1 / 4,
        child: Container(
          decoration: const ShapeDecoration(color: Colors.yellow, shape: CircleBorder()),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text('2'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also can be used inside Stack

```dart
class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  const CustomWidget({Key? key, required this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          // container one
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: color,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
        ),
        FractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: 1 / 4,
          heightFactor: 1 / 4,
          child: Container(
            decoration: const ShapeDecoration(color: Colors.yellow, shape: CircleBorder()),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text('2'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Other than that passing size(Ozan Taskiran post) or using LayoutBuilder can used.